# Having trouble with populating ComboBox2 based on ComboBox1

Tags: powershell

I am trying to populate ComboBox2 based on selection of ComboBox1

Code Snippets:

```
$mySite = (Import-CSV .\mytest.csv | Group-Object Site | foreach-object { $_.group | select -Last 1 | select site })
# $ComboBox1 = "S12"
$thisone = (import-csv .\mytest.csv | % {
        $ADSNames = $_.site.split(",") 
        $Site = $_.Site
        $dept = $_.dept
        foreach ($name in $ADSNames)
        {
            if ($name -eq $Combobox1)# $name)
            {

            }
        }
    })

####################################################################################################    
#####   Create Combo Boxes
####################################################################################################
    #
    $Combobox1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Combobox
    $Combobox1.Location = '35,25'
    $Combobox1.Size = '50,20'
    $Combobox1.Items.AddRange($mySite.site)

    $combobox2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Combobox
    $combobox2.Location = '130,25'
    $combobox2.Size = '50,20'
    $combobox2.items.Add($thisone.dept)

    $Form.Controls.Add($combobox1)
    $Form.Controls.Add($combobox2)
```

If I highlight only the following code:

```
# $ComboBox1 = "S12"
$thisone = import-csv .\BOP-Sites.csv | % {
    $ADSNames = $_.site.split(",") 
    $Site = $_.Site
    $dept = $_.dept
    foreach ($name in $ADSNames)
    {
        if ($name -eq $Combobox1) # $name)

        {
        write-host $dept
        }
    }
}
```

The Write-Host shows only the lines that match the ComboBox1 "Run Selected Commands" (see below)

```
KK0
DDD
HH1
BB2
VV4
ZZ3
SSS
WW4
QQ5
JJJ
```

Below is the code to populate ComboBox2

```
$ComboBox1.add_SelectedIndexChanged({
$combobox2.Items.Clear() # Clear the list
$combobox2.Text = $null  # Clear the current entry
Switch ($ComboBox1.Text) {
        $thisone {

            $dept | ForEach { 
            $combobox2.Items.Add($_)
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately I can not get ComboBox2 to properly populate

Comment: That is a very wrong way to set your value `$ComboBox1 = "S12"` Whenever you do that, you discard  entirely the combo box object you just created with `$Combobox1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Combobox` and replace it with a string. To set the selected item, you need to use `$Combobox1.SelectedItem = '512'`

Comment: The S12 in the code is a Sample. I am importing a CSV file that contains 500 records (2 columns)  50 different values in the Sites column and each site has multiple Department values in Column 2.

Comment: What format is your data in? Post a sample line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your data is in the format:

[image]

Then:

```
$csvlocation = 'c:\temp\book1.csv'

$SiteData = Import-CSV $csvlocation


Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms


$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Text = "Foo"
$form.Size = '400,400'

$Combobox1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Combobox
$Combobox1.Location = '35,25'
$Combobox1.Size = '50,20'
$Combobox1.Items.AddRange($SiteData.site)

$combobox2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Combobox
$combobox2.Location = '130,25'
$combobox2.Size = '50,20'


$form.Controls.AddRange(@($combobox1,$combobox2))


$ComboBox1.add_SelectedIndexChanged({
    $combobox2.Items.Clear() # Clear the list
    $combobox2.Text = $null  # Clear the current entry
    $ThisSite = $SiteData | Where-Object { $_.Site -eq $ComboBox1.Text } 
    ($ThisSite.Dept).Split(',') | ForEach-Object {
        $combobox2.Items.Add($_)
    }
    $Combobox2.SelectedIndex = 0
})

# Show form
$form.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
$form.Dispose()
```